# Multiple JVMS writing to the same log file in Log4j2 version 2.3

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

We are upgrading a legacy application to use log4j2. Because the application server (Weblogic 10.3.6.0) doesn't support servlet 3.0 we are at a cap of servlet 2.5 and can go as high as version Log4j version 2.3.

We have 4 JVMs running on the application server. We have 1 log4j2 config per server, so all 4 JVMs use the same config. We can seperate out the log files by appending the JVM name.

We were wondering if it's possible we can remove the JVM name, and have all JVMs write to the same logger? We are not able to use the async logger, and think there may be synchronous file locking issues.

Can anyone confirm if we can combine the log outputs of all 4 JVMS to 1 file, or it is better to separate them out per JVM.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have multiple JVMs write to the same file you must use file locking (locking="true" on the File Appender). However, file locking is not supported on the RollingFileAppender as it cannot be done safely. File locking will also impact the performance of writing to the log files.

Answer (score 0):

try this [SharedRollingFileAppender](https://github.com/droolsassert/droolsassert/blob/master/da-utils/src/main/java/org/droolsassert/util/SharedRollingFileAppender.java)
config file [log4j2.yaml](https://github.com/droolsassert/droolsassert/blob/master/da-utils/src/test/resources/log4j2.yaml)
test [SharedRollingFileAppenderTest](https://github.com/droolsassert/droolsassert/blob/master/da-utils/src/test/java/org/droolsassert/util/SharedRollingFileAppenderTest.java)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.droolsassert</groupId>
  <artifactId>da-utils</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Additional parameters:**

**fileLock** - path to the file to be used for shared locking (will be created if needed). The same lock can be used for different appenders.

**resourceLock** - path to the resource to be used for shared locking (must not be packed within archive).

**messageQueueSize** - message queue size to be used as a buffer for asynchronous processing to soften heavy file locking operations time
default 1K.

**writerThreadKeepAliveTimeSec** - if value is greater than zero, it is used as a time to shut down background non-daemon writer thread guarantee messages flush to thefile system in the background thread but not prevent normal JVM shutdown when idle. Rare messages may experience short delays (~0.3s) starting worker thread. If value iszero, endless daemon worker thread is started not preventing normal JVM shutdown but without any guarantee of messages processing before shutdown. This approach has no writetime delays and continuous worker thread recreation after idle times (suitable for long running applications).
default 3